# Compass not working on my mobile devices in Chrome 39

Tags: html, google-chrome, device-orientation

I've seen many examples of HTML5 compass, yet none works on my Sony Xperia M phone and Lenovo S5000 tablet. Compass works properly in applications on both devices.

How to make the compass work in Google Chrome 39?

Examples:
http://jamesgpearce.github.io/compios5/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/deviceorientationsample.html
http://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-device-orientation-events
http://richtr.github.io/Marine-Compass/

None of them works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the device support the event using

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
   alert("DeviceOrientation is supported");
}
```

Or similar. Modernizr does not appear to support feature detection for this.

Comment: DeviceOrientation is supported.

Comment: Then use javascript to emit the values either to and alert or to html - so you can see if values are propagating through to the browser. Otherwise likely a bug ... try validating all your html, javascript and css

Comment: None of the example pages work for me. I am not creating my own compass, just trying available demo pages. No demo works on my devices.

Comment: Can you update the Android version? Are you on KitKit / Lollipop? If it does not work in-browser then either the data is not exposed to the browser on those devices, or they are not standard.

Comment: Phone is version 4.3, tablet is 4.4.2. I cannot upgrade.